# Is the Asteroid Belt in a plane that intersects Earth and Jupiter?

Tags: asteroid-belt

Is the Asteroid Belt in the same plane as Earth and Jupiter or they are in different planes?

Answer (score 11):

This question is similar to: [Do the planets, asteroid belt, kuiper belt, and scattered disk lie on the same plane?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/do-the-planets-asteroid-belt-kuiper-belt-and-scattered-disc-lie-on-the-same-p)

[Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) is on the [ecliptic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic), [Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter) is 1.305° inclined relative to the ecliptic, so not quite coplanar but pretty close.

The [asteroid belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_belt), being made up of a diverse set of rocks, is all over the place (from [here](http://burro.astr.cwru.edu/stu/advanced/asteroid.html)):

[image: Asteroid inclination]

The description of that image:

> The orbital inclination histogram [above], which is binned in intervals of 0.1°, shows that asteroids are another exception to this rule. The average orbital inclination is about 8.2°.

Between planets (especially Jupiter) perturbing orbits of asteroids and asteroids occasionally hitting each other and breaking apart the asteroid belt isn't stable enough to gather into a planet or even a single plane or type of orbit.  To present the orbits differently, [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_belt#/media/File:Asteroid_proper_elements_i_vs_e.png) from Wikipedia shows the grouping of asteroids in similar orbits:

[image: Asteroid proper elements, inclination vs eccentricity]

Where

- $i_p(^\circ)$ is inclination from the [ecliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic) in degrees
- $e_p$ is orbital [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) from 0=circular to 1=a [maximally elongated](https://www.mathopenref.com/ellipseeccentricity.html) ellipse

and the subscript $p$ stands for [proper orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_orbital_elements) (a kind of average over time) which are distinct from current or [osculating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_orbit) orbital elements. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_family#Description

Comment: Using your first diagram as a guideline, a vast majority of the asteroids are within 15 degrees, which isn't nearly as planar as the 8 planets, but it's still much more planar than random.     Minute physics has a good video that's loosely related:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmNXKqeUtJM